# Доступ к моделям из библиотеки

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Всем привет. Проектирую приложение на Ruby on Rails. Часто используемые части приложения, думаю, стоит поместить в библиотеку (lib/). Возник вопрос: возможен ли доступ к моделям из библиотек без «костылей»?

Comment: А зачем? имхо, библиотека не должна зависеть от конкретной модели.

Answer (score 1):

Пиши библиотеки с автономной логикой, а модель может выступать как параметр в экземпляре данного класса.

Или же создай модуль, в него запихни все что нужно, а потом этот модуль инклуд в модель.

Например [вспомогательная модель для юзера](https://github.com/galetahub/sunrise-core/blob/master/lib/sunrise/models/user.rb)